# Xamarin.Forms - Sync movements/scrolling of 2 carouselviews

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.carouselview

How to "sync" the scrolling/movement of 2 carouselviews?

~ A - B - C - D ... This is the items of carousel 1

~ E - F - G - H ... and this is the items of carousel 2

When I scroll to B from A, I'd like to expect the same goes for carousel 2 in which it moves from E to F.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

edit: btw, they're on the same page

Comment: what have you tried?  There is a Position property that you could bind to the same VM property, or you could use the PositionChanged event of one to update the other

Comment: In this case, I want to sync their animation while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

> When I scroll to B from A, I'd like to expect the same goes for
> carousel 2 in which it moves from E to F.

Yes, you can monitor event `PositionChanged` of your carouselview, of event `PositionChanged` is triggered, you can also scroll another carouselview to special position.

Please refer to the following code:

```
    private void mCarouselView1_PositionChanged(object sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int previousItemPosition = e.PreviousPosition;
        int currentItemPosition = e.CurrentPosition;

        mCarouselView2.ScrollTo(currentItemPosition);
    }

    private void mCarouselView2_PositionChanged(object sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int previousItemPosition = e.PreviousPosition;
        int currentItemPosition = e.CurrentPosition;

        mCarouselView1.ScrollTo(currentItemPosition);
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the answer. But this kind of method results in the time lag for the thing to respond, which I don't want.

Comment: The lag here means, let's say I swipe/scroll the upper carouselview (let's just short it to cv1 and cv2), the moment my finger taps the screen and move, cv2 should also follow the movement, not just cv1.

Comment: That's what I meant by syncing the animation or the movement, sorry if it's unclear.

Comment: Why not fill  your data into a ScrollView?